# pyspark - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to group by multiple columns and rank them by count and get the top record for each group.However when I call the groupby I get the following error.

```
df.groupby("_c21","y2_co","y2_r","y2_z","y2_org").count()\
    .show(n=10)
```

I've tried grouping by a single column that is not null

```
df.groupby("_c21").count()\
    .show(n=10)
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Sample rows

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+----+-----+--------------------+
|                _c17|                _c21|                   m|y2_co|y2_r| y2_z|              y2_org|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+----+-----+--------------------+
|proc=;app=;cl=442...|tHO$SZPbABVo3A1X8...|[proc -> , app ->...|   BR|  PB|58397|Voax Provedor de ...|
|proc=;app=;cl=444...|tHO$SZPbABVo3A1X8...|[proc -> , app ->...|   BR|  PB|58397|Voax Provedor de ...|
|proc=;app=;cl=145...|Zu6zZxiekXnHfpNER...|[proc -> , app ->...|   MX| NLE|66490|           Totalplay|
|proc=;app=;cl=145...|Zu6zZxiekXnHfpNER...|[proc -> , app ->...|   MX| NLE|66490|           Totalplay|
|proc=;app=;cl=147...|Zu6zZxiekXnHfpNER...|[proc -> , app ->...|   MX| NLE|66490|           Totalplay|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+----+-----+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a `.show(n=5)` in the previous statement. I commented out the `.show(n=5)` and it works.

```
df.withColumn('m', F.expr("str_to_map(_c17,';','=')")) \
                .select("*",*[F.col('m')[k].alias(k) for k in keys])
#               .show(n=5)
```